# How to zip contents recursively under the directory foo/*.*?

Tags: zip

> zip -r /tmp/foo/bar.zip /tmp/foo/* > /dev/null 2>&1

and the achieve is in this structure

```
   /tmp
      /foo
         file1
         file2
         dir1/
           file3
         dir/2
           file4
```

Why is `/tmp` part of the structure?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is because you tell it to do that ;-)

I would do something like this:

```
cd /tmp && zip -r /tmp/bar.zip ./foo/* >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: Why `**` instead of `*`?

Comment: where do you see **? >:D (no idea where that came from :X )